# In photoelectric effect, what is effect of frequency?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

So what does the frequency of the light in photoelectric effect does ? Does it increases number of electrons?

Comment: If you increase the frequency of light than the threshold frequency of metal,  then remaining energy after absorption by metal is increased than previous time . This increases the speed and never of ejected electrons...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research. Please read this meta post: [What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778). Pretty much every article about the photoelectric effect will talk about effects of changing the frequency: it's one of the most important results observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the frequency of the incident radiation determines how much energy there is per photon. high frequency means high energy. if the energy per photon is insufficient to overcome the electron work function of the surface, no photoelectrons will be ejected- no matter how many photons hit it. If the photon energy is above that threshold, then electrons will be ejected. at that point, more photons (stronger light beam) mean more ejected electrons.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency determines the energy of a photon of light. When a photon is absorbed by an electron, the electron gains the energy of the photon and according to the energy gained it is either released from the atom or jumps to an higher orbital shell around the atom. But the energy required by and electron to be released by an atom depends on the frequency of the light applied. For example even if a huge amount of red light is applied to the electron, it wont be released from the atom due to the lower energy of the red light. But even a slight amount of higher frequency blue light can cause the electron to be released, due to the higher energy of the blue light. This clearly shows us that the behaviour of an electron when exposed to light depends on the frequency of the light, not the intensity of the light. This solution is further explained by the equation:

*E = hv*

which shows that the energy of a photon equals the product of a  constant known as Planck's constant(h) and the frequency of the light(v).

The value of the Planck's constant is equal to *6.626070040818181818181818
x10-34 J s.*

The minimum energy of light required to release an electron depends on the work function of the material. Also the kinetic energy of the released electron depends on the energy of the photon and thus on the frequency.

Comment: Just so you know, the (81) in Plancks constant is the standard uncertainty of the last two digits, not a recurring decimal.